# Saving ID to SQL table that it's not a Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have a html select tag (dropdown) that is has Products. Each Product has its respective ID in a table called Products in the database.

I also include an option in the select called "any product" so the user can select all products to be shown when a search is done. I set the option "any product" the value 0 and I'm saving with 0 in the database.

I'm saving these searches stats in a table called ProductsSearched. The question is: is it OK to save this option with ID 0? Because this won't match any ProductID from the table Products. I won't be able to use FK from this table to the ProductsSearched.

On the other side, If I add an option "Any Product" in the Products table and assign an ID it also won't be OK because it could be misused in other tables referencing a specific product ("any product" is not a product).

Is there a standard or best way to save this data in this scenario?

Many thanks!

Comment: probably best to add a dedicated "don't care" field into your table, to signify that it's an anything record.

Comment: what about with a nullable foreign key?  then something like (@Product is null or ProductID = @Product)

Comment: Thank you, I can use this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table ProductSearches is used for logging I would not even bother with fk to another tabel.  I think it's better to just write out the value of the search.  This way you won't have troubles later on if the values in the Product table should change somehow.